# What is wrong with my routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

```
    root :to => "index#home"

    #public tattoo viewing and submissions
    match "/submit" => "index#new", :via => :get
    match "/tattoo" => "index#create", :via => :post
    match "/tattoo/:id" => "index#show", :via => :get
    match "/tagged" => "index#tagged", :via => :get
    match "/tattoo/:id" => "index#destroy", :via => :delete
    match "/tattoos" => "index#index", :via => :get

    members section and its nested images
    resources :members, :except => [:new, :create] do
        resources :tattoos
    end
```

Thats whats in my routes.rb file. They produce:

```
root        /(.:format)                          {:controller=>"index", :action=>"home"}
                   submit GET    /submit(.:format)                    {:controller=>"index", :action=>"new"}
                   tattoo POST   /tattoo(.:format)                    {:controller=>"index", :action=>"create"}
                          GET    /tattoo/:id(.:format)                {:controller=>"index", :action=>"show"}
                   tagged GET    /tagged(.:format)                    {:controller=>"index", :action=>"tagged"}
                          DELETE /tattoo/:id(.:format)                {:controller=>"index", :action=>"destroy"}
                  tattoos GET    /tattoos(.:format)                   {:controller=>"index", :action=>"index"}
                  members GET    /members(.:format)                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"members"}
              edit_member GET    /members/:id/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"members"}
                   member GET    /members/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"members"}
                          PUT    /members/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"members"}
                          DELETE /members/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"members"}
```

But i have a problem. For some reason, when I try to go to mysite.com/submit

I used to get this error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"images"}
```

on

```
<%= form_for @tattoo, :html =>{:multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

but that has magically changed to:

```
undefined method `images_path'
```

on the same line.

when my controller has this:

indexcontroller
     def new
        @tattoo = Image.new
      end

```
  def create
    @tattoo = Image.new(params[:image])

    if @tattoo.save
      flash[:success] = "Tattoo sent in for approval!"
      redirect_to(images_path)
      else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
```

And then this link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Manage tattoos", member_tattoos_path() %>
```

give me this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"tattoos"}
```

I thought I was beginning to understand routes and had a decent grasp but I dont get whats going on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edit_member_path` should know the id of the member you want to edit. Please try

```
<%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_member_path(@member) %>
```

For `No route matches {:controller=>"images"}`; since the action image is not defined in your route, please try to stop and restart the server and check if there is any plugin like Paperclip in place.

Comment: see, I was hoping to have that link to a page where the current user can edit their own profile, so I just changed the link_to to <%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_member_path(current_user) %>

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in a member object to `edit_member_path`.

```
<%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_member_path(@member) %>
```